# Multiply list numbers and print the total (aggregation)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a basic Python script that allows me to multiply each number in a list and print the total.

For example, if my list contains 2, 5, 1, I want the script to multiply 2 * 5 * 1 which would give 10. For some reason, I am unable to produce this, I have been able to produce it by adding numbers together (which you can see below) but when I change line 8 to multiply, it doesn't give me the expected result (in the above example, it gives me 30 instead of the expected 10).

Incorrect multiply list total:

```
# input list
numbers = [2, 5, 1]
# output list
total = 0
# for each number in the list:
for number in numbers:
    # update total
    total = total + number * number
# print the total
print(total)
```

Script which successfully adds numbers in a list together:

```
# input list
numbers = [2, 5, 1]
# output list
total = 0
# for each number in the list:
for number in numbers:
    # update total
    total = total + number
# print total
print(total)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To multiply the numbers in a list and print the total, you need to set the total to 1 and you need to use the *= operator. This simply means "[left hand side expression] = [itself] * [right hand side expression]"

```
# input list
numbers = [2, 5, 1]
# output list
total = 1
# for each number in the list:
for number in numbers:
    # update total
    total *= number
# print total
print(total)
```

This prints 10 (2 * 5 * 1 = 10)

Answer (score 2):

Idiomatic way to do such things is [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) — literally to "reduce" your sequence element by element and end up with single value. If you need multiplication, you can use [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/operator.html#operator.mul) — programmatic way to do multiplication:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

total = reduce(mul, [2, 5, 1])
```